# Does Salesforce Locker Service has full support for svg?

Tags: locker-service, svg-icon

I am working on enabling locker service for our org and we are using progressbar.js to render some of the metrics. However, I find that the progressbar.js throws up errors when locker service is turned on.

**After doing a root cause analysis, I find that the error is due lack of support for some of the svg functions like getTotalLength() when locker service is turned on.**

Can anaybody tell me if Salesforce is fixing any of these issues w.r.t svg when Locker Service is turned on? Or it's up to us to fix these issues?

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: @DougChasman might be able to answer this, so I'm adding a mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locker ***should*** provide full access to the SVG APIs but it looks like it's missing some (e.g. SVGPathElement). There are no open cases/bugs on this currently however. If you open a support case and please let them known you've already been in contact with the Locker team (I have already opened bug *W-3567163* to track this) and we will get this fixed quickly. Locker's design requirements mandate a secure by default (blacklist) approach and we typically simply need to perform a security review on the requested API and then add it to the metadata that drives the blacklist.

Comment: Thank you for your response and for opening a bug. Will surely reference this if in case I open a support case. I just wonder if we will hit some other roadblock once this is fixed since we are fixing these things iteratively. I think that's the way things are with respect to Locker Service.