# SVG API incomplete in LWC/Locker

Tags: locker-service, lightning-web-components, svg

I want to create a custom component that wraps the [yFiles for HTML](https://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml) graph drawing component in an LWC component, but it seems some of the SVG API is not implemented or rather hidden behind the locker API.

Running this code in any HTML5 compatible browser outside of the locker API works:

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use").href.baseVal = "something"
```

However the `href` property is not implemented and yields `undefined` inside an LWC context or the locker console and thus code like the above breaks the third party library like this:

```
Cannot set property 'baseVal' of undefined
```

Is this intended or is this just an oversight? The Locker API viewer does not seem to mention any SVG APIs, at all. Are they supposed to work or are they all unsupported. My initial tests show that some parts seem to be working, at least.

[image]

Comment: Seems this might be just a matter of enabling the [SVGURIReference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGURIReference) API like in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/152354/64786